# Does WCF Service Reference Skip the Types

Tags: c#, asp.net, wcf

I have three projects: a UI (web), a WCF service, and a type library (with business objects).
I have included the type library in both the UI and the WCF service.
I have created a service reference to the service from the UI.

When I look at the Object Browser for the service reference in my UI project, it does not have all of the object types in there. I suspect it's not coincidental that the types it's missing are the types I have because I included the type library.

**My question is this: is my service reference being smart and recognizing that it doesn't need to create types (in the proxy) for the types that I already have a reference to?** Everything is working excellent and I like the behavior so I'm not complaining... just wondering. It's great having the reference to the actual type library because then all of my getters and setters work even in the consumer (my UI).

Comment: Are your types decorated with `DataContract` attributes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at reference properties. You will find a "Reuse types from referenced assemblies..." switch. Having this turned on means that the proxy generator reuses classes it can access locally, at the client side.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't need the reference to your type library.

By adding a service reference in Visual Studio your UI web project will then generate all the object types it needs from consuming the service.

That said your current behaviour may stem from  the "Reuse types from referenced assemblies" which will only generate the classes it can't access already locally.

Comment: I actually want the reference to my type library. I realize that it's not necessary and that is perfect for most distributed apps (where a service architecture prevails!), but in our case, including the type library allows us to use the getters and setters that our entities contain.

Comment: @Jeremy I missed that bit, What advantage does having the getters and setters gain? I only ask as i've always just consumed a service to get the correct objects and types generated, would you mind giving an example?

Comment: Yeah. First of all, you not only get the getters/setters, but any properties you've marked as [IgnoreDataMember]. We use it to turn some resulting codes (think state code i.e. "WA") into values ("Washington") using lookup libraries that are only on the client side. We could do this with an extension method or something, but we've put it in the business objects. Now that I think about it, I think almost anything could be replaced and not make it necessary to reference the BO library, but I'm glad it's an option.